# What is the grinding sound made by the Borg in Star Trek Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

I've noticed that in Star Trek Voyager, the Borg almost always make a strange wet grinding sound. Is this breathing, joints moving, or something else entirely? There's hardly anything about Star Trek sound design that I can find in general, and nothing at all about the Borg.

Example:
[Scene from Dark Frontier](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bkw69E_C4g)

If you listen closely you can hear a grinding sound amidst the other borg sounds.

Comment: You'd best find an example on youtube.   Otherwise VTC for "not clear what you're asking."     I imagine the sound you are talking about is just supposed to be the sound of their servo motors, but I can't be sure from your description.

Comment: Example added as an edit.

Comment: Do you mean that whirring sound?   Can you give an exact time mark?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about the the individual drone's servo controls. When Seven of Nine was still a drone she made the same sound while moving.